# Java JDBC Query with variables?

Tags: java

```
String poster = "user";

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `prices` WHERE `poster`="+poster);
```

This does not work.Any tips or tricks would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Try surrounding the `poster` variable with single quotes, like this:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `prices` WHERE `poster`='"+poster+"'");
```

That's because SQL expects strings to be surrounded by single quotes. An even better alternative would be to use prepared statements:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `prices` WHERE `poster` = ?");
stmt.setString(1, poster);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

It's recommended using `PreparedStatement` since the way you are currently building the query (by concatenating strings) makes it easy for an attacker to inject arbitrary SQL code in a query, a security threat known as a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @Ken anyway, consider using prepared statements (for the reasons outlined above). And if you're satisfied with the answer, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

1) In general, to "parameterize" your query (or update), you'd use JDBC "prepared statements":

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

2) In your case, however, I think all you need to do is add quotes (and lose the back-quotes):

```
// This is fine: no back-quotes needed
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM prices");


// Since the value for "poster" is a string, you need to quote it:
String poster = "user";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = 
  stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM prices WHERE poster='" + poster + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

The Statement interface only lets you execute a simple SQL statement with no parameters. You need to use a PreparedStatement instead.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("
                          select * from 
                          prices where 
                          poster = ?");

pstmt.setString(1, poster);
ResultSet results = ps.executeQuery();
```