# mySql connect to Java-debugging query

Tags: java, mysql

I have established a connection with mySql and Java and currently I can run a query from my database. I can run queries such as "Select * from Customer".
The problem appears, when i try to scan a value from the user and try to run it in my db.

```
    select E.rent_id, name, telephone, Pa.date_get, Pr.date_return
    from Rent as E, Customer as P, Get as Pa, return as Pr, Makes as Pg
    where E.rent_id =  Pg.rent_id
    and Pg.cust_id = P.cust_id
    and E.rent_id = Pa.rent_id
    and E.rent_id = Pr.rent_id
    and Month (Pa.date_get) = @input
    and Year (Pa.date_get) = @input;
```

This is a query, which selects an id, a name, telephone, and dates of get and return of a vehicle (this is a db for a car rental company).
Unfortunately, when I connect to my db via Java, using the connector, I can't run this query.
Do you have any idea what to do? 
Here follows the code in java that makes the connection and the use of the query, stated above.

```
    package database;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    public class Connect {

public void databaseConnect(String connect_string, String username, String password) {
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connect_string, username, password);
        System.out.println("Connection Succesful");
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

        System.out.println("Insert month: ");
        int mina = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Insert year: ");
        int xrono = scanner.nextInt();
        String query = "select E.rent_id, name, telephone, Pa.date_get, Pr.date_return\r\n" + 
                "from Rent as E, Customers P, Get as Pa, return as Pr, makes as Pg\r\n" + 
                "where E.rent_id =  Pg.rent_id \r\n" + 
                "and Pg.cust_id = P.cust_id \r\n" + 
                "and E.rent_id = Pa.rent_id \r\n" + 
                "and E.rent_id = Pr.rent_id \r\n" + 
                "and Month (Pa.date_get) = @mina  \r\n" + 
                "and Year (Pa.date_get) = @xrono;";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(4));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(5));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connect connectToServer = new Connect();
    connectToServer.databaseConnect("jdbc:mysql://localhost/acr", "/*username*/", "/*password*/");
}
```

}

Can you see a mistake? 
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: This might be a good place to start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8461713/7109162) gives you 2 possible solutions to use user input inside a query

Comment: Thank you guys, I just solved it!